# Is the field formed by algebraic elements of an extension field over $F$ isomorphic to $F[t]$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Say $K/F$ is a field extension. The elements in $K$ that are algebraic over $F$ form a subfield of $K$. Is this subfield isomorphic to $F[t]$? What would this isomorphism look like?

This is not a textbook problem. This is what I inferred from a statement made in a well-known textbook on Algebraic Geometry. I only want to verify if what I inferred is true.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math.SE! In this site, when you post questions, you should also write your thoughts: this includes the source of the problem, the motivation, and what you think is the answer or at least how to think about it.

Comment: If $K$ is an algebraic extension, doesn't that mean that *every* element of $K$ is algebraic over $F$? So the subfield is $K$ itself?

Comment: @Mathmo123- The assumption is that $K$ is not an algebraic extension.

Comment: In which case, you should edit your question... currently it says "Say K is an algebraic extension of field F"

Comment: @Mathmo123- Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Notes:

1. $F[t]$ is a field iff $t$ is algebraic over $F$. When $t$ *is* algebraic over $F$, then you can construct this field as the quotient $F[t]\cong F[X]/(m)$ where $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $F$. The mapping is the obvious one.
2. It is not common for a subfield of algebraic elements to be just generated by a single $t$. Consider $\Bbb Q$ and the elements algebraic over it inside $\Bbb C$.

Comment: (of course, you need to pick a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: One may as well say that an algebraic extension $E$ of $F$ is of the form $F[t]$ only if $E/F$ is {\it finite}. If, further, it is _separable_, then ("theorem of the primitive element") there is a single $t$.

Comment: @rschwieb: I misread and thus misunderstood the intent. I'll delete my comment.